# Java Eclipse - Select, enter integer and display string

Tags: java

My question is

Which is your favorite fruit?

1) Apple

2) Banana

3) Orange

Your Selection : __

I'll enter 3 and I would like to print out, Your favorite fruit is Orange.

How can I display as Orange instead of 3?

Comment: System.out.println("Which is your favorite fruit?");

System.out.println("1) Apple");

System.out.println("2) Banana");

System.out.println("3) Orange");

System.out.print("Your Selection: ");

selectFruit = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Your favorite fruit is : " + selectFruit);

Comment: @girishlalwani2010: Please, when you provide an answer, note that it should be useful not only for OP but for future readers as well. In its current state, your answer is a mere comment, nothing more. Add at least an explanation about *why* to use `HashMap` and *how* (probably some code). Also, since this question is obviously an exercise in order to learn about Java, it would be better by not showing a whole code solution at once but providing an explanation for OP to generate its own code.

Comment: Since you're new to the site, please note that you can edit your questions and add more relevant info regarding the problem.

Comment: Do you know about arrays or just `if`/`else` statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//selectfruit 1 ,2,3? lets suppose 

int selectfruit = 3;

if(selectfruit == 1) {
System.out.println("Apple");

} else if(selectfruit == 2){

   System.out.println("Banana");

} else if(selectfruit == 3) {

  System.out.println("Orange");

}
```

output will be **Orange** as you want.

Answer (score 1):

So now you have edited the question, so your logic should be like this:

```
if(selectFruit == 1) {
   //Print Apple
}
//Do same for other fruits.
```

But in this case, it's better to use `switch-case` statement. But I will leave that as a excercise to you. Learn more about switch-case statement [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the worst code I'd ever written:

```
System.out.println("Which is your favorite fruit?");
System.out.println("1) Apple");
System.out.println("2) Banana");
System.out.println("3) Orange");
System.out.print("Your Selection: ");
int selectFruit = input.nextInt();

switch(selectFruit)
{
   case 1: System.out.println("Apple"); break;
   case 2: System.out.println("Banana"); break;
   case 3: System.out.println("Orange"); break;
   default System.out.println("?\nPardon?")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can print the fruit name in if() statement like that:

```
if(selectFruit == 1)
{
System.out.println("Apple");
}
else if(selectFruit == 2)
{
System.out.println("Banana");
}
else if(selectFruit == 3)
{
System.out.println("Orange");
}
```

you can do it in one more way, switch-case, it is nicer to read:

```
switch(selectFruit)
{
case 1:
System.out.println("Apple");
break;
case 2:
System.out.println("Banana");
break;
case 3:
System.out.println("Orange");
break;
}
```

few notes:
* in the if statement, if there is only 1 line of code, you don't have to use {}.
* in the last statement in switch-case you dont have to use break.

hope it is useful,
good luck :)

Comment: Don't advise people to drop the {} in an if statement, it's poor practice and you'll notice that static code checkers [like PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/rules/java/braces.html) will flag it.  Same goes for the break advice, that's also just an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: well, i hope that the person who ask it want to know as much as he can. he don't have to use it. i am always keeping my {} in the codes but i know that i can drop them. well, you are right, it is just for knowladge :)