# Exit Menu if else in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

Please enter your choice or enter 0 to exit menu

```
if(selectfruit == 1) {
    System.out.println("Apple");

} else if(selectfruit == 2){

    System.out.println("Banana");

} else if(selectfruit == 3) {

    System.out.println("Orange");

} else if (selectfruit == 0) {
```

What should I type in the else if option to exit the menu? Please help!

Comment: "Goodbye" seems good.

Comment: Please add more context like exit to/frow where? If you want to stop your app you can use `System.exit(0)`

Comment: Why not use `switch`?

Comment: @EricJablow Because it wasn't the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559535/java-eclipse-select-enter-integer-and-display-string

Comment: دەزانی ئەتوش زۆر بلعی ها ، توخوا ئەوە پرسیارە؟

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exit from your app then u can use

```
else if (selectfruit == 0) {
System.exit(0);

}
```

or if you wants to write some message to your console then you can write message some thing like "by by "

```
else if (selectfruit == 0) {
System.out.println("by by ");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you leave it blank, it will not write nothing and continue your application, and if there is nothing to do it will exit.
**Only** if there is more commands after those conditions.

```
if (selectfruit == 1) {
    System.out.println("Apple");
}
else if (selectfruit == 2){
   System.out.println("Banana");
}
else if (selectfruit == 3) {
    System.out.println("Orange");
}
```